# how to limit cart products Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6 and I want to limit the total number of products in the cart.

For example I can't add a product for more than 3 times:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: and what have you tried..........

Comment: @thickguru i tried overriding Cart.php the function updateQty, i followed this tutorial https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/325631-solved-limit-quantity-order-for-all-products/

Comment: Did you delete class_index.php on cache/ folder ?
its the way to "enable" override

Comment: Seriously the questions lately on prestashop...

Comment: hi @Mepps yes i clear the cache folder

Comment: @TheDrot what that means ? do you have any solution ?

Comment: You can't add more than 3 products to cart... is there specific module you have? Maybe you don't have enough products in stock to add more than 3 items? Or maybe I just don't understand what you want?

Comment: @TheDrot As I understand he wants to limit, for example, maximum 2 unit of that product, regardless of the quantity in stock, the customer can't buy more of that quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the cart product in `upQuantity()` function defined in `cart-summary.js` in your prestashop front theme folder.

Comment: Happy to help you... @theCoder